# How to define a function on an object and still be able to run it to set initial object properties

Tags: javascript

The code below raises an error, saying that `this.getDateString()` is not a function.

```
const Model = function () {

  let dateParam = this.getDateString();

  this.getDateString = function() {
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    let month = date.getMonth()+1;
    let day = date.getDate();
    return year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
  }
}
```

I think this is because the function isn't hoisted, so it doesn't exist when I run it in the beginning of the file. I could of course change the function definition:

```
const Model = function () {

  let dateParam = getDateString();

  function getDateString() {
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    let month = date.getMonth()+1;
    let day = date.getDate();
    return year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
  }
}
```

But I don't want to do that, because other functions are using the function from outside of the `Model` object. Is there some special trick to use here instead? Move the function definition to the top maybe? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add this property on `this` and assign that function

```js
const Model = function () {

  let dateParam = getDateString();

  this.getDateString = getDateString;
  function getDateString() {
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    let month = date.getMonth()+1;
    let day = date.getDate();
    return year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
  }
}
```